# консольная игра с помощью библиотеки ncurses

Tags: c, ncurses

пишу простенькую игру на си с помощью библиотеки ncurses и возник вопрос как сделать движения ботов постоянными, а не чтоб они ждали пока я введу что-либо с помощью getch()(движение моего персонажа реализовано через ввод с клавиатуры 1 нажатие 1 сдвиг)

Comment: Нужно реализовать так называемый `game loop`.

Comment: `int nodelay(WINDOW *win, bool bf);`

Answer (score 2):

> как сделать движения ботов постоянными

Наиболее простой и очевидный способ - завести отдельную нитку на каждого бота, внутри которой он "шагает" с заданным шагом по времени, не завися ни от кого другого.

Плюс отдельная нитка для игрока, в которой обрабатываются нажатия клавиш.

Но тут есть проблема. Большая... Ncurses не дружат с многопоточностью. Точнее говоря, должна быть только одна нитка, в которой используется библиотека. В ней и больше - нигде.

Моя рекомендация по этому поводу:

1. В функции майн запускаете по одной нитке на каждого бота, одну нитку - для обработки нажатий клавиатуры и ещё одну нитку - для отрисовки экрана игры.
2. С окном игры работает только эта нитка - одна! Она выбирает команды отрисовки из общей для всех нитей очереди и выполняет указанное рисование.
3. Нити ботов крутятся в бесконечном цикле, засыпая на шаг игры, потом генерируют своё перемещение и помещают команду на отрисовку этого перемещения в общую очередь.
4. Нить игрока висит на ожидании ввода с клавиатуры и, при нажатии клавиши, помещает соответствующую команду отрисовки в очередь отрисовки.

Очередь отрисовки обязательно должна быть огорожена мюьтексами, так как это - общий ресурс. Структуру сообщений (команд) в этой очереди придумайте сами. Ну, например "Стереть изображение бота в точке X1,Y1 и перерисовать его в точке X2,Y2". Ну и так далее...